# Is s:form specific to struts2 framework?

Tags: java, struts2, struts

Is "s:form" specific to the struts2 framework or can we use it in the struts1 framework also?

Answer (score 1):

Tags in the "s" namespace (`<s:XXX>`) are specific to Struts2. You can't use the `s:` tags in Struts 1.

Answer (score 0):

`s:form` is indeed [specific to struts 2.0](http://www.javabeat.net/qna/139-sform-struts-20/). The `s` namespace was first introduced in 2.0.